# How to Mock IUrlHelper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Getting started with Unit Tests can be frustrating, getting stuck at every detail. Hope this will improve as I gain more experience.

Now, how do I  mock `IUrlHelper` for unit test?

I have this simple method to get absolute paths in ASP.NET

```
public static string AbsolutePage(this IUrlHelper url, string pageName, string pageHandler = null, object routeValues = null)
{
    return url.Page(pageName, pageHandler, routeValues, url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
}
```

Mocking the Scheme is easy

```
return Mock.Of<IUrlHelper>(x =>
    x.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme == "http");
```

but then the method calls the Page method on the `IUrlHelper`. What do I do now?

I'd be tempted to skip small frustrating tests like this, but I think it's important to be vigorous when first learning.

Comment: actually, it's important to focus on what is important to test. you don't have to test and mock everything. Focus on the basics, get those right, then everything will fall into place. Test your own functionality, not frameworks

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu: is right. You're mostly testing the framework here. Extensions are very difficult to unit test, so the general idea is that they should be kept minimal and mostly just proxy to code that can/is thoroughly tested. Here, the only thing that could possibly go wrong is if you literally passed the parameters wrong to `url.Page`, which is mostly covered by compile-time checking. In short, there's no real need to test this method at all.

Answer (score -2):

If you still want to test your `IUrlHelper` you may use this code

```
var mocked = new Mock<IUrlHelper>();

mocked.Setup(x => x.Page(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                    .Returns("whatever_string");

IUrlHelper helper = mocked.Object;
```

Comment: Ya. That would test that Page gets called; but not that it's generating the expected absolute URLs in a variety of scenarios, so the test would be of limited use really. And since the inner-working of the function is a bit complex, I can't say it works until I run it. And the fact that it uses the UrlHelper to generate the absolute URLs is an internal matter that ideally the test wouldn't care about -- as long as it provides the expected result.

Comment: I found back this post after bumping into the same issue again. Page is an extension method in UrlHelperExtensions and not a member of IUrlHelper, thus it can't be mocked in that way.